# PostgreSQL calling procedure from inside function into timestamp

Tags: postgresql

This code exists inside a function, and CalculateDate(x,y,z,...) is a procedure, and end_dt is of type timestamp.

It doesn't seem to like the way that I am assigning what returned from Calculated to end_dt. So I am guessing the reason is it doesn't like using the "into" keyword.

Any thoughts? Thanks.

```
    call CalculateDate(
       cast(par_asof_dt as timestamp), 
       cast('PB' as varchar), 
       cast('OPS' as varchar), 
       cast(end_dt as timestamp), 
       par_msg_txt, 0) into end_dt;
```

Comment: Functions return values, not Procedures although you can use OUT/INOUT arguments to pass values.

Comment: `calculatedate` should be a function, the this is as simple as `end_dt := calculatedate(...);`